# how to safely pass a variables value between threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I read on the python documentation that Queue.Queue() is a safe way of passing variables between different threads. I didn't really know that there was a safety issue with multithreading. For my application, I need to develop multiple objects with variables that can be accessed from multiple different threads. Right now I just have the threads accessing the object variables directly. I wont show my code here because there's way too much of it, but here is an example to demonstrate what I'm doing.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import random

class switch:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id=id
        self.is_on = False

    def self.toggle():
        self.is_on = not self.is_on

switches = []
for i in range(5):
switches[i] = switch(i)

def record_switch():
    switch_record = {}
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)
        current = {}
        current['time'] = time.srftime(time.time())
        for i in switches:
            current[i.id] = i.is_on
        switch_record.update(current)

def toggle_switch():
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.random()*100)
        for i in switches:
            i.toggle()

toggle = Thread(target=toggle_switch(), args = ())
record = Thread(target=record_switch(), args = ())

toggle.start()
record.start()
```

So as I understand, the queue object can be used only to put and get values, which clearly won't work for me. Is what I have here "safe"? If not, how can I program this so that I can safely access a variable from multiple different threads?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you have threads modifying a value other threads can see, then you are going to have safety issues. The worry is that a thread will try to modify a value when another thread is in the middle of modifying it, which has risky and undefined behavior. So no, your switch-toggling code is not safe.

The important thing to know is that changing the value of a variable is not guaranteed to be **atomic**. If an action is atomic, it means that action will always happen in one uninterrupted step. (This differs very slightly from the database definition.) Changing a variable value, especially a list value, can often times take multiple steps on the processor level. When you are working with threads, all of those steps are not guaranteed to happen all at once, before another thread starts working. It's entirely possible that thread A will be halfway through changing variable `x` when thread B suddenly takes over. Then if thread B tries to read variable `x`, it's not going to find a correct value. Even worse, if thread B tries to modify variable `x` while thread A is halfway through doing the same thing, bad things can happen. **Whenever you have a variable whose value can change somehow, all accesses to it need to be made thread-safe.**

If you're modifying variables instead of passing messages, you should be using a[**`Lock`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects)object.

In your case, you'd have a global `Lock` object at the top:

```
from threading import Lock

switch_lock = Lock()
```

Then you would surround the critical piece of code with the `acquire` and `release` functions.

```
    for i in switches:
        switch_lock.acquire()
        current[i.id] = i.is_on
        switch_lock.release()

    for i in switches:
        switch_lock.acquire()
        i.toggle()
        switch_lock.release()
```

Only one thread may ever acquire a lock at a time (this kind of lock, anyway). When any of the other threads try, they'll be blocked and wait for the lock to become free again. So by putting locks around critical sections of code, you make it impossible for more than one thread to look at, or modify, a given switch at any time. You can put this around any bit of code you want to be kept exclusive to one thread at a time.

EDIT: as martineau pointed out, locks are integrated well with the `with` statement, if you're using a version of Python that has it. This has the added benefit of automatically unlocking if an exception happens. So instead of the above `acquire` and `release` system, you can just do this:

```
    for i in switches:
        with switch_lock:
            i.toggle()
```

Comment: If the `switch` class is only intended to be used in a multithreaded setting, it might make sense to integrate the lock in the object, and put the locking logic into `toggle` itself. Reading a `bool` is always going to be atomic, so you don't need to synchronize between writers and readers unless the data within a switch gets more complicated (multiple fields that all can be changed). Also, you should probably use `with` statements to handle locking and unlocking in an exception-safe manner.

Comment: `lock` objects support the context manager protocol -- see [_Using locks, conditions, and semaphores in the `with` statement_](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement). This means the example code could be simplified by using `with switch_lock:` followed by statement(s) which access the shared variable(s). It also mean the lock would be released automatically if an exception is raised.

Comment: @martineau thanks for pointing that out - at work I'm stuck with Python 2.4.3, so I don't get to experience the wonderful world of `with`. Feel free to edit my answer with a good example.

Comment: I see you've updated your answer yourself with this information. Besides the obvious convenience of acquiring and releasing the lock, the exception-safety afforded by using `with` statements is a very significant feature. IMHO when answering SO questions, it's important to mention things available in later versions -- assuming you're aware of them -- even if you don't have access to them yourself for whatever reason.

Comment: @martineau I do try to do this when I can. In this case I had no idea that locks worked with the `with` statement. And yea, I figured I might as well update on my own so long as I was still at my computer. I just wanted to give you credit :)

Comment: what about the switches array or for that matter, the objects themselves? do they also need to be surrounded by a lock object?

Comment: @user3741394 if you have threads changing the array or the object, then yes, they should also be surrounded by a lock object. Anything that multiple threads have access to should be locked for safety's sake.

Comment: so if I am merely referencing the variable, or finding its value, but not changing it, do I then need a lock?

Comment: @user3741394 if you have a variable whose value will never change, you don't need to lock it. Otherwise yes. I'll explain more in an edit.